# Android Studio Could not get resource Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I tried to build sample project, but getting this error on build.

> Could not GET 'https://us-west2-maven.pkg.dev/gmp-artifacts/transportation/com/google/android/libraries/mapsplatform/transportation/transportation-consumer/1.0.19/transportation-consumer-1.0.19.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

The module build.gradle file looks like the following:

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.1.5"
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "artifactregistry://us-west2-maven.pkg.dev/gmp-artifacts/transportation"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
```

The project build.gradle file looks like the following:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlinVersion = "1.6.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
       classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
 }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

     }
  }
```

Comment: Did you get solution for this issue ?